# Variable scope incorrectly set-up in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, scope

The following is a MCVE of my try at BattleShip in NodeJS.
`Grid.set` calls `Grid.place` which calls `Grid.place.methodPlace` which tries to call `Grid.cells` and fails. This is not the way to access such a variable, since `this.cells` is not in scope. What is the correct way of accessing this variable?

I'm probably making a mess of it. Beginners do that.

```
"use strict";
function Grid(x, y) {
  var r, c, row;
  this.cells = [];
  this.default = " ";
  for(r = 0 ; r < x ; r++) {
    row = [];
    for(c = 0 ; c < y ; c++) {
      row.push(" ");
    }
    this.cells.push(row);
  }
}

Grid.prototype.place = function(length) {
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  };

  var coordinateList = [];
  function methodPlace(indexOfMethodToUse) {
    if (indexOfMethodToUse == 0) {
      var rndX = getRandomInt(0,(9-length));
      var rndY = getRandomInt(0,9)
      for(var i = 0 ; i <= rndX + length ; i++) {
        if (this.cells[rndX+i][rndY] == this.default) {   // <=====
          coordinateList.push(rndX+i,rndY);
        }
      };
    }
    console.log(coordinateList);
    return coordinateList;
  }
  methodPlace(0);
};

Grid.prototype.set = function(ac) {
  for(var i = 0 ; i <= ac ; i++) {
    this.place(2);
  }
}

var friendlyGrid = new Grid(10,10);
friendlyGrid.set(1,2,1,1);
```

Comment: You could make `methodPlace` a normal method, so it can access `this` like `place()` and `set()` can. If it's private on purpose, you need this way and you'll have to do `self = this` or something to make `this` accessible in your private method. Or you can manually call `methodPlace` with this: `methodPlace.call(this, 0)`

Comment: @Rudie It's private on purpose for so far that I thought this would keep the structure clean. This is the method using the function so there's no reason to put it on a higher layer, right?

Comment: No reason, but probably cleaner, more readable, better debuggable, simpler syntax etc. No need for `.call()` and/or `self` because it's a normal method. If it's not private for a good reason, I'd just make it public. The `.call()` solution is pretty readable and short too though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least 2 solutions:

1. Make the method public, like `set()` and `place()`
   If you do that, it's callable with `this.methodPlace(0)` and it would know `this`.
2. Use `.call()` to inject context
   If you do that, it's callable with `methodPlace.call(this, 0)` and it would know `this`.

If there's no good reason to have the method be private, I'd make it public: more readable, cleaner, better debuggable, simpler syntax etc. If there is a good reason for it to be private (access), I'd use `.call()`

There's another solution:

3. Copy `this` to `self` and use that internally
   I don't like this, because there'll be `self` and `this` floating around, but you could copy the class/object `this` to `self` and use `self` instead of `this` in the private method (where `this` has changed):
   (this is panta82's solution, but using `self` instead of `that`, which illustrates my dislike)

.

```
var coordinateList = [];
var self = this;
function methodPlace(indexOfMethodToUse) {
  // ... //
      if (self.cells[rndX+i][rndY] == self.default) {   // <=====
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Grid.prototype.place = function(length) {
  var that = this;
  // ... the rest of the code
```

Then later, use "that" instead of "this".